# Remapping `i` key in all shortcuts in vim

Tags: vim, remap

I'm trying to interchange `i` and `l` keys in vim. I've succeeded in all modes except for one issue. After pressing `di` vim receives `di` instead of `dl` and thus, instead of deleting the character to the right vim waits for another key to be pressed to execute the corresponding shortcut. If another key is pressed then vim acts executing `dl + key` since the remap is working. At the same time, if `dl` is pressed vim also waits for a key to execute a shortcut and this time the shortcut is correctly executed since, again, the remap works correctly.

So my question is, why is does vim recieve `di` after pressing pressing `di` and executes `dl` and receives `di` too after pressing `dl` but executes `di`?

In the next picture I pressed `di` and vim received `di` but executes `dl` after pressing another key.
[image]

In the next picture I pressed `dl` and vim received `di` and executed the key combination correctly.
[image]

The only difference is `di` vs `"+di` I can't interpret.

Remaps are the following:

```
" Movement Remapping
" Down
noremap n gj
" Up
noremap e gk
noremap E K
" Right
noremap i l
noremap I L
" Preserve Insertion
noremap l i
noremap L I

" Next Search Result
noremap k n
" Previous Search Result
noremap K N


" Forward end of word
noremap j e
noremap J E

" Enables writing in snippets selection
sunmap n
sunmap N
sunmap e
sunmap E
sunmap i
sunmap I
sunmap l
sunmap L
sunmap j
sunmap J
```

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sure @romainl. Question has been updated.

Comment: You are right, comments were wrong. They've been corrected. I'm trying to map neovim commands related to movement my keyboard distribution which is colemak. In order to do that I've written those maps. My main problem is with 'di', the rest of the mapping works and 'J' command can be remmaped too. So, if 'Your problem with di is very likely to be caused by a race condition between your mapping noremap i l and the built-in text objects mechanism (:help text-objects).' I need to know if that can be solved.

Comment: Wrong place for your comment. Also, Vim commands are mnemonic so the location of the keys is immaterial: if you know your keyboard layout, then you don't need to change anything in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Vim commands are not "maps" so those things are not "remaps", they are "mappings".

You seem to be confused about quite a few things…

- The mapping under `Up` goes down.
- The mapping under `Down` goes up.
- The first mapping under `Left` goes up.
- The second one goes nowhere because `K` is not even a motion: `:help K`.
- The second mapping under `Right` goes down, to the last line of the window.
- The third one enters insert mode to the *left* of the current character.
- The fourth one enters insert mode to the *left* of the first printable character.
- The second mapping under `For inverse order search` is the only one of the two that relates to "inverse order search".
- The second mapping under `Forward end of word` overrides the very useful `:help J`.

Your problem with `di` is very likely to be caused by a race condition between your mapping `noremap i l` and the built-in text objects mechanism (`:help text-objects`).

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with all those mappings but overriding things like `J` or `K` or disabling entirely some of Vim's most powerful features doesn't sound like a good idea to me, *especially with comments that contradict the code*.

You should give this more thought.